# How can I iterate through this list with modular variables

Tags: python

Let's say I have one file called colours.py that contains this:

```
black = (0, 0, 0)
aqua = (0, 255, 255)
```

And my main.py file contains:

```
import colours

colour_list = ['black', 'aqua']

for i in colour_list:
    colour = colours.i[0]
    print(colour)
```

I get AttributeError: module 'colours' has no attribute 'i'

How do I iterate through it to access the first index of each variable?

Comment: `i` is being assigned an element from the list. In the first iteration, `i` is `'black'`, in the second, `i` is `aqua`.

Comment: Try printing `i` in the loop without that `colour` assignment statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference variables with the name as string like you do here (or you can, but it's using some obscure mechanism of python like reading variables from globals instead by reference).

Instead, it's better if you import the variables and use directly their references.

```py
from colours import black, aqua

colour_list = [black, aqua]

for colour in colour_list:
    print(colour) #For the complete variable 
    print(colour[0]) #For the first index
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not defined in colours module, and it will not (and should not) be replaced with the value it represents. The best way to access some values by different strings is to contain them in a dictionary.

```
cols = {
    "black" : (0, 0, 0),
    "aqua" : (0, 255, 255)
}


colour_list = ['black', 'aqua']

for i in colour_list:
    print(cols[i])
```

Ofc you can still extract the `cols` definition into a separate file and import it like usual.